# Getting Process-Id of firefox or Chrome Tab thourgh Browser Javascript APIs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, http, firefox

Is there any way that web client loaded onto Chrome or Firefox browser know the process-Id of browser or browser tab(in case of Chrome)? My web client needs some unique attribute from browser environment .. so that it can communicate that unique attribute to server as its ID for some period (may be for a session) .. I thought, process-id may serve the purpose to some extent ..

Thanks

Comment: You can just generate a UID,.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't have access to information like that from JavaScript.